# How to ignore Sonarqube's 1000 line limit in Python: greater than 1,000 authorized

Tags: python, sonarqube

How can I instruct Sonarqube to suppress the following warning for a specific python file:

```
File "foo.py" has 2,345 lines, which is greater than 1,000 authorized. Split it into smaller files.
```

In the past I've used the `# NOSONAR` comment to suppress a warning at a specific line, but given that this warning is at the file level instead of the line level, I don't think it would work.

I would prefer to suppress this warning for a specific file instead of suppressing this warning for all files, as this warning is useful in most other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it directly with Sonarqube, but in the Jenkins property file I used the following successfully:

```
# Turn off these rules
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=e1
# python:S104 "Files should not have too many lines of code"
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey=python:S104
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey=path/to/specific/file.py
```

To figure out the rulekey needed to be `python:S104`, I went into my companies code quality portal, where there was a tab on the top called `rules`. In here, there was a `python` tab. I scrolled down the list and found an entry called:

```
 Files should not have too many lines of code
```

Which, incidentally, is not the same warning that a scan of the code base gives.

Clicking on that entry listed `python:S104` as the rule key.